# How to implement a many to many relations with Android Room Persistence Library?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

How to implement a many to many relations with Android Room Persistence Library?

One user may have one or many devices & One device may be owned by one or many users.

[image: User device]

```
@Entity
public class User {
  public @PrimaryKey Long id;
  public String userName;
}

@Dao
public interface UserDao {
  @Query("select * from user") List<User> getAllUsers();

  @Query("select * from user where id = :id")
  User getUserById(long id);
}

@Entity
public class Device {

   public @PrimaryKey Long id;
   public String name;

}


@Dao
public interface DeviceDao {

    @Query("select * from device")
    List<Device> getAllDevices();
}


@Entity
public class UserDevice {
    public String userId;
    public String deviceId;
}

@Dao
public interface UserDeviceDao {

// List all devices by userId
// List all users by deviceId

}
```

Comment: Your code seems to implement an M:N relation, with `UserDevice` representing the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a typo in `UserDevice` so id's are `Long` instead of `String`:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"userId", "deviceId"})
public class UserDevice {
    public Long userId;
    public Long deviceId;
}
```

You could try:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDeviceDao {

    // List all devices by userId
    @Query("select * from device " +
           " inner join userdevice on device.id = userdevice.deviceId " +
           " where userdevice.userId = :userId")
    List<Device> getUserDevices(Long userId);

    // List all users by deviceId
    @Query("select * from user " +
           " inner join userdevice on user.id = userdevice.userId " +
           " where userdevice.deviceId = :deviceId")
    List<User> getDeviceUsers(Long deviceId);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a typo in the @Query

```
@Query("select * from user where user_id = :id")
User getUserById(long id);
```

Comment: This should not be an answer. Either suggest an edit (given you do not have enough reputation) or post a comment to the OP. In either way, the typo is irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: At the time of writing, I didn't have enough permission to comment